How to send email using Gmail Api and ASP.NET Core Web API?
I am working on a POC using ASP.NET Core Web API and the Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 NuGet package to send emails via the Gmail API, as SMTP-based email sending will no longer be supported after September 30 2024.
I am currently testing this locally. I created a project in the Google Developer Console and generated an OAuth client ID by selecting the web app option. I have enabled the Gmail API:


I get the error as shown in the above screenshot. During testing, I noticed an issue where the last digits of the URL in the error message ('http://127.0.0.1:62415') keep changing each time I run the application. Could this be happening because I'm testing it locally?
Will this error be resolved if I host this REST API in Azure App Service?
Is there any way to test locally?
Here is my code:
using GeoConnect.Clients;
using GeoConnect.EmailPOC;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;

namespace GeoConnect.EmailSendingPOC;

public class EmailSendingPocService : ApplicationService
{
    private readonly string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };
    private readonly string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Example";
    private readonly string ClientId = "";
    private readonly string ClientSecret = "";
    private readonly IRepository<EmailSendingPoc, Guid> _tokenRepository;

    public EmailSendingPocService(IRepository<EmailSendingPoc, Guid> tokenRepository)
    {
        _tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }

    public async Task SendEmail(string to="test.vishnukumarps@gmail.com",string from= "test.vishnukumarps@gmail.com")
    {
        try
        {
            var credential = await GetUserCredential();

            // Create Gmail API service
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            var email = CreateEmail(to,from , "Subject", "Hello, this is a test email!");
            var message = new Message
            {
                Raw = Base64UrlEncode(email)
            };

            // Send the email
            await service.Users.Messages.Send(message, "me").ExecuteAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task<UserCredential> GetUserCredential()
    {
        var secrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            ClientSecret = ClientSecret
        };

        var token = await _tokenRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token?.Token))
        {
            // Create a UserCredential object using the stored token
            var credential = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = secrets,
                    Scopes = Scopes
                }),
                "user",
                new TokenResponse { AccessToken = token?.Token }
            );
            return credential;
        }

        var newCredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new NullDataStore() // No data store in this case
        );

        // Save the token to the database
        // await _tokenRepository.SaveTokenAsync("user", newCredential.Token.AccessToken, newCredential.Token.Expiration);
        await _tokenRepository.InsertAsync(new EmailSendingPoc()
        {
            Token = newCredential.Token.AccessToken
        }, true);

        return newCredential;
    }

    private string CreateEmail(string to, string from, string subject, string body)
    {
        var message = new StringBuilder();
        message.AppendLine($"To: {to}");
        message.AppendLine($"From: {from}");
        message.AppendLine($"Subject: {subject}");
        message.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        message.AppendLine();
        message.AppendLine(body);

        return message.ToString();
    }

    private static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
            .Replace('+', '-')
            .Replace('/', '_')
            .Replace("=", "");
    }
}


This question is similar to: Google Oauth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch - Port changed on callback. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What's your current url now? I mean 127.0.0.1 or localhost?
